# Workaround for PIVOT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query, is taking like 2 minutes to resolve, I need to find a workaround, I know that UNPIVOT has a better solution using CROSS APPLY, is there anything similar for PIVOT?

```
SELECT [RowId],  [invoice date], [GL], [Entité], [001], [Loc], [Centre Cout], [Compte_1], [Interco_1], [Futur_1], [Department], [Division], [Compagnie], [Localisation], [Centre/Cout], [Compte], [Interco], [Futur], [Account], [Mobile], [Last Name], [First Name], [license fee], [GST], [HST], [PST], [Foreign Tax], [Sales Tax License], [Net Total], [Total], [ServiceType], [Oracle Cost Center], [CTRL], [EXPENSE], [Province]
        FROM 
                (SELECT fd.[RowId], fc.[ColumnName], fd.[Value]
                    FROM dbo.FileData fd
                INNER JOIN dbo.[FileColumn] fc  
                    ON fc.[FileColumnId] = fd.[FileColumnId]               
                WHERE FileId = 1
                    AND TenantId = 1) x
        PIVOT
        (
        MAX(Value)
        FOR [ColumnName] IN ( [invoice date], [GL], [Entité], [001], [Loc], [Centre Cout], [Compte_1], [Interco_1], [Futur_1], [Department], [Division], [Compagnie], [Localisation], [Centre/Cout], [Compte], [Interco], [Futur], [Account], [Mobile], [Last Name], [First Name], [license fee], [GST], [HST], [PST], [Foreign Tax], [Sales Tax License], [Net Total], [Total], [ServiceType], [Oracle Cost Center], [CTRL], [EXPENSE], [Province])
        ) AS p
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivots are great, but so are Conditional Aggregations.  Also, there would be no datatype conficts or conversions necessary

```
SELECT [RowId]
      ,[invoice date] = max(case when [FileColumnId] = ??? then Value end)
      ,[GL]           = max(case when [FileColumnId] = ??? then Value end)
      ,... more fields
 FROM  dbo.FileData fd
 WHERE FileId = 1
  AND TenantId = 1
 Group By [RowId]
```

> **EDIT**

You could add back the join to make it more readable.